# How can I wait for the object to end spinning and then play the animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class RoboSphereWindowBreakInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public InteractableObjects interactableObjects;
    public AudioClip audioClip;
    public float speed;

    private bool hasStarted = false;
    private Animator anim;

    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B) || (hasStarted == true)))
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

            hasStarted = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Square 1")
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            hasStarted = false;
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("Wall_Window_Long_03"));
        }
    }

    public void ActivateRoboSphere()
    {
        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            if(child.name == "Camera")
            {
                RepositionCamera(child);
            }
        }

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.enabled = true;

        StartCoroutine(PlayAudio());
    }

    private void RepositionCamera(Transform camera)
    {
        var Eyes = GameObject.Find("eyeDome");

        camera.position = Eyes.transform.position + Eyes.transform.forward;
        camera.LookAt(Eyes.transform);
        camera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
    }

    IEnumerator PlayAudio()
    {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        audio.clip = audioClip;
        audio.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);

        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
        StartCoroutine(Spin(3f, rotation));

        anim.SetBool("Roll_Anim", true);
    }

    IEnumerator Spin(float lerpTime, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;

        while (elapsedTime <= lerpTime)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, elapsedTime / lerpTime);
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But when the animation start the object spin but not facing the target at least not the target I wanted.

The object the sphere start rotating facing the window(in the screenshot in the background in the  top scene view) but then it's changing the facing back facing the camera(the camera that is child of the transform).

The method ActivateRoboSphere call RepositionCamera and ActivateRoboSphere is being called once when clicking the mouse in a on click event.

But for some reason when the object is playing the "Roll_Anim" animation it's facing the camera again and not the window the target.

I marked the window target where it should face at with red square in the screenshot :

[image: Facing the robosphere child camera on the left and not the window target marked with red square]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can make your calling `IEnumerator` wait until the other one is finished by simply `yield`ing it like

```
...

// executes and at the same time waits for Spin to finish
yield return Spin(3f, rotation);

// called when Spin routine is finished
anim.SetBool("Roll_Anim", true);
```

---

Alternatively instead of a third-party tool library like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60601657/7111561) you could simply add a callback like

```
IEnumerator Spin(float lerpTime, Quaternion rotation, Action whenDone)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    while (elapsedTime <= lerpTime)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, elapsedTime / lerpTime);
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}
```

and then start the routine either using a lambda expression like

```
StartCoroutine(Spin(3f, rotation, () => 
{
    anim.SetBool("Roll_Anim", true);
}));
```

or a method call like

```
private void AfterSpinning()
{
    anim.SetBool("Roll_Anim", true);
}

...

StartCoroutine(Spin(3f, rotation, AfterSpinning));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a tween engine, like http://dotween.demigiant.com/.

If you install Dotween then you can simply use

```
transform.DORotate(new vector3(0 ,100 , 0) , duration);
```

You can also set Ease for tweens. or use Oncomplete functions;

```
transform.DORotate(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration)
    .SetEase(Ease.OutCubic)
    .OnCompelete(() => { shouldClose = true; });
```

You can also set a loop for your tween `.SetLoops(-1)`.

In addition to this, you can use `sequences` to show multiple tweens together.